# Why this simple Linux C program loading .so at runtime crashes?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, function-pointers, dlsym

I am trying to write the tiniest program loading a shared object (.so) of mine too at runtime.

Unfortunately, it hangs at runtime despite doing error checking :-(

I am very interested in what I overlooked on source code level.

The source code and my shell session running my program follows.

File "libsample.c" :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sample_check(void)
{
    printf("INFO: Function sample_check() called.\n");
}
```

File "test.c" :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef void (*sample_func_t) (void);

int main(void)
{
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    setbuf(stderr, NULL);
    void* h_lib = dlopen("./libsample.so.1", RTLD_LAZY); // RTLD_LAZY || RTLD_NOW
    if (! h_lib)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR(%d): %s\n", __LINE__, dlerror());
        return 1;
    }

    sample_func_t* symver = NULL;
    dlerror();
    symver = dlsym(h_lib, "sample_check");
    char* reter = dlerror();
    if (reter)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR(%d): %s\n", __LINE__, reter);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("INFO(%d): Resolved library sample_check() symbol at %p\n", __LINE__, symver);
    printf("INFO(%d): About to call library sample_check() ...\n", __LINE__);
    (*symver)();
    printf("INFO(%d): sample_check() called !\n", __LINE__);

    int retcl = dlclose(h_lib);
    if (retcl)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR(%d): %s\n", __LINE__, dlerror());
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

File "build" :

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Begin of compilation ..."

rm test test.o libsample.so.1 libsample.so.1.0.1 libsample.o 2>/dev/null

gcc -fpic -c -o libsample.o libsample.c || exit 1

gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libsample.so.1 -o libsample.so.1.0.1 libsample.o || exit 1

ln -s libsample.so.1.0.1 libsample.so.1 || exit 1

gcc -c -o test.o test.c || exit 1

gcc -o test test.o -ldl || exit 1

echo "Compilation successful !"
```

My shell session log :

> ```
> valentin@valentin-SATELLITE-L875-10G:~/PROGRAMMING/C/Libraries/libsample$ 
> valentin@valentin-SATELLITE-L875-10G:~/PROGRAMMING/C/Libraries/libsample$ ./build 
> Begin of compilation ...
> Compilation successful !
> valentin@valentin-SATELLITE-L875-10G:~/PROGRAMMING/C/Libraries/libsample$ ./test 
> INFO(27): Resolved library sample_check() symbol at 0x7f5e96df86f0
> INFO(28): About to call library sample_check() ...
> Erreur de segmentation
> valentin@valentin-SATELLITE-L875-10G:~/PROGRAMMING/C/Libraries/libsample$
> ```

Any idea ?

Comment: On an unrelated note, are you *sure* you want to make `stdout` unbuffered? And you do know that `stderr` is unbuffered by default?

Comment: Did you check that dlsym returned a non NULL value. If it returns NULL that does not necessarily mean an error - it meas that the symbol was simply not found.

Comment: At worst, superfluous dlerror() call clears the error status again. I didn't forget to check dlsym() status using dlerror() in file test.c lines 19..25 .

Comment: And dlsym() call return value is assigned to variable 'symver' previously initialized to NULL. When reading this variable I got pointer 0x7f5e96df86f0 (changing from one run to one another), which is obviously not NULL .

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
 (*symver)();
```

the code dereferences what had been received as entry point for library function to be run. This resolves to a random address, which, when being called, typically crashes the program.

To fix this define

```
sample_func_t symver = NULL;
```

where `samle_func_t` already is a pointer type because of

```
typedef void (*sample_func_t) (void);
```

<sup>(Mind the `*`.)</sup>

Then there are two possibilities to assign `symver`:

1. The "dirty" one

   ```
    symver = dlsym(h_lib, "sample_check");
   ```

   "dirty" as the compiler might issue a warning like this:

   ```
    ISO C forbids assignment between function pointer and ‘void *’
   ```
2. The "cleaner" one

   ```
    *(void**)(&symver) = dlsym(h_lib, "sample_check");
   ```

And finally call the function like this:

```
symver(); /* No need to dereference here. */
```

Comment: I am not sure about the syntax to use here to call into the entry point I just gained ; please tell me. Thx ( Note it's the entry point of a simple void func_name(void) like thing. )

Comment: Nice catch : stupid fingers ! It was obviously the typo on line 17 : the superfluous asterisk ! That kind of typos sometimes happen to me when I switch from unreadable things like *(void*$#!(void))()... to more readable typedefs. In the same spirit as copy/paste bugs.